# Ansible wait_for rebooting

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible, developer-tools

I'm trying to use ansible to configure the environment I have to use. In particular, I need to write a task that reboots the servers, so I wrote this task:

```
- name: waiting for server to come back
  local_action: wait_for 
    host={{ ansible_hostname }}
    port=22
    state=started 
    delay=50
    timeout=300
  sudo: false
```

but the task fails reaching the time-out even though servers are correctly restarted.

I was wondering if it fails because of my ssh configuration. The connection to these servers is done through a Proxy (`ProxyCommand` in `~/.ssh/config`).

---

```
FROM VERBOSE OUTPUT

<servername> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: username

<servername> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=False -o Port=22 -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=username -o ConnectTimeout=10 -tt hostname

...

fatal: [servername -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 300, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"connect_timeout": 5, "delay": "10", "exclude_hosts": null, "host": "hostname", "path": null, "port": "22", "search_regex": null, "state": "started", "timeout": "300"}, "module_name": "wait_for"}, "msg": "Timeout when waiting for host:22"}
```

I don't know if relevant but in the output:

```
hostname != servername: hostname = foo, servername = foo.bar.com
```

I think `hostname=ansible_hostname` while `servername=inventory_hostname`

---

Ansible version: ansible 2.0.1.0

Comment: Could you execute with `-vvvv`? I've just tried this code on a server that it's also accessed with ProxyCommand and it worked just fine.

Comment: I have pretty much the same task and also use ProxyCommand and that works. I'm not entirely sure but I believe this was the reason I had to disable ssh sessions (ControlMaster). Do you use ssh sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a connectivity problem. To get rid of this problem I've increased the ssh timeout.

One simple way to do that it's creating a `ansible.cfg` file in the same directory of the ansible script and put inside this content:

```
[defaults]
timeout = xx
```

where xx for me was 30.